# AWS Simple AD NIS Domain

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services

I have deployed a simple AD directory service in AWS but when I go to adsiedit / AD user and computers I cannot assign an NIS domain / unix attributes to my users so I can configure them to be able to login via SSSD / ssh. I know I can use the local ID mapping in Linux, but would like to use the uid number / gid information from AD to do this so can have consistency across all of my boxes. I do not see the Identity Management for Unix utils on the workspaces machine I am using to manage the environment so was looking where this can be added so I can configure the attributes for the users. Any help you can give would be appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 1):

The attributes you're looking for are generally referred to as [RFC2307](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2307.txt) attributes. They have been a default part of the AD schema since at least as far back as Windows Server 2003.  They consist of the following:

**User attributes**

- gecos
- gidNumber
- uid
- uidNumber
- loginShell
- msSFU30NisDomain
- unixHomeDirectory

**Group Attributes**

- gidNumber
- msSFU30NisDomain

The GUI pieces you're looking for to manage these attributes were part of the Identity Management for Unix (IDMU) and NIS Server roles. But in Windows Server 2012 R2, those roles were deprecated and then Microsoft removed them from Windows Server 2016 which has caused a bit of confusion in the community.

Don't worry though, the attributes haven't been removed. Only the GUI to manage them has. There is a TechNet blog post called [Clarification regarding the status of Identity Management for Unix (IDMU) & NIS Server Role in Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview and beyond](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/activedirectoryua/2016/02/09/identity-management-for-unix-idmu-is-deprecated-in-windows-server/) that explains in more detail.

Ultimately, you need to manage the attributes directly either via scripting or via the Attribute Editor tab in *Active Directory Users & Computers* or *Active Directory Administration Center*.
[image: Attribute Editor]

To use the Attribute Editor from ADUC, you first need to enable *Advanced Features*
[image: Advanced Features]

Comment: Ryan...thanks for the feedback.  Yes, I can make the changes directly in adsiedit / attribute editor, just wanted to make sure was not an issue since in 2012 had the NIS domain feature to do it.  If this is the same, then will just assign the GID / uid number to the user and add in their uid to the group members attribute.  Thanks for the feedback / info.